# How can I wait until a specific drop-down menu selected using Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, exception, web-crawler, wait

I made a crawler for this page (http://www.bobaedream.co.kr/cyber/CyberCar.php?gubun=I) to collect the stock list of specific manufacturers. The process is to start from selecting the drop-down menu in the first row of upper part of search menu.

[image]

Each right drop-down menu is child menu of its left drop-down menu. What I would like to do is to select each first item in each drop-down menu and click the "search" button for the first run. After crawling of its stock list, then I set the second item of the last drop-down menu and click the "search" button.

But the problem is occurred here. I saved each items of each drop-down menu as tuple. When I try to call the second item of the last drop-down menu for the second round of crawling, "StaleElementReferenceException" or "NoSuchElementException" is occurred with the message of "Element is no longer attached to the DOM". Thus, I would like to make the element wait until the entire round of each drop-down iteration is completed.

Below is my code, but still have the error message. My error usually occurs at the second while loop. At this moment, I guess some type of "wait.until(EC.~)" code in the second "try" function can work this out, but I have no specific idea for this. Please help or give me any advice.

```
def option2_menu_loaded(inDriver):
    path = '//select[@id="level2_no"]'
    return inDriver.find_element_by_xpath(path)

self.wait.until(option2_menu_loaded)

while True:
    try:
        select_option2_values = [
            ('%s' % o.get_attribute('text'), '%s' % o.get_attribute('value'))
            for o
            in self.getNewSelect("#level2_no").options
            if o.get_attribute('text') != '세부등급']
    except (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException):
        print("Exception Found")
        continue
    break

for option2 in select_option2_values:
    self.csv.setCarTitle(ma, mo, de, option1[0], option2[0])

    print(option2[0], option2[1])
    self.driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)

    while True:
        try:
            self.getNewSelect("#level2_no").select_by_value(option2[1])
        except (StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException):
            self.getNewSelect("#level2_no").options
            print("Exception Found")
            continue
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you google the StaleElementException you will see solutions that try to find again the element within a loop. So **that is one idea**, in your exception above try 3 times with 1 sec delay before each try to find_Element again, see if this helps.

**Another idea** is to refresh the page (certainly not ideal but it might work) between every crawl. You can do this in Python using:

```
driver.refresh()
```

Finally, you can also avoid looping (this might be causing the StaleElementException) through all the different elements when crawling as Selenium has a solution for that. You can save eveything in tuple/array without looping through each record by **using** **find_ElementS** instead of *find_ElemenT*. Try this see if it improves your overall performance:

```
a=[];
a = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(path)
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried with "driver.refresh()" + "driver.implicitly_wait(1)" code in the exception part. When the first exception occurs, it helps to get out of the exception part during the loop. But, It got stuck again in the while loop after 3~4 escapes from the exception. For the third comment, I tried it for the first time when I made this code at the beginning, but it returned cache out error. Do you have any idea?

Comment: The only idea that springs to mind regarding a cache error when trying to find elements is probably your xpath locator. It needs to be generic and not specific to one element. For example 
NOT this: //div[@class='buy']//div[@class='cars']//p[@text='Honda'] but this instead //div[@class='buy']//div[@class='cars']//p[@text]. Notice how the last Xpath is not specific enough so it will bring all cars instead of just Honda cars. So perhaps posting here (update your question) a bit of the html code surrounding your Xpath might help!

Comment: Probably you have already tried this one as well, but it looks that your website contains frame. If that is the case you need to switch webDriver focus to the appropriate frames before trying to find the element: 1)driver.SwitchTo().Frame(Name) 
2)driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()
     3) driver.FindElement(By.XPath(XpathLocator)); element.Click();